# Reading a Map from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value

Tags: java, spring

I have a list of (key/value) need to be populated to a map on a spring bean:

> ```
> dmin.details.fieldsMap=name,Abdullah,\
>              street,Zayed,\
>              phone,+201020102010
> ```

It's working fine with me using a list as below:

**property:**

> dmin.details.fields=Abdullah,Zayed,+201020102010

**Calling:**

```
@Value("#{'${dmin.details.fields}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> fields;
```

**Could anyone advise if this is doable in Spring?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

application.properties:

```
property.map={first:value, second:value}
```

then in Java code you can:

```
@Value("#{${property.map}}")
Map<String, String> map;
```

Comment: It should be `property.map={first:'value', second:'value'}`. Also worth to notice it requires spring 4.1+ (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9472)

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't find any way in spring to read the property as a Map, I had to fill the map myself using the list filled by spring as below :

```
@Value("#{'${dmin.details.fields}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> fields;

private Map<String, String> fieldsMap;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    fieldsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (fields != null && fields.size() != 0) {
        for (String field : fields) {
            String[] splittedField = field.split(",");
            fieldsMap.put(splittedField[0], splittedField[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly different case and explaining that below, in case if somebody is looking for it.

1. I had trade_id_date={'123WC':'20100125', '234W':'20100125', 1689332:'20100125'} in properties file
2. Below in a java class

   @Value("#{${trade_id_date}}")
   private Map tradeIdDateMap;

If you do not enclose the left hand side in single quotes if it is alphanumeric then you will get

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException
@0: EL1044E: Unexpectedly ran out of input
```

3. So make sure you enclose that in single quotes

Comment: Thank you, I ran into this and your post did help !

Comment: @basu76 - you can vote my comment if it was helpful :)